# Install Postgresql + Postgis on CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, postgis, centos7

I can see that CentOS 7 ships with Postgresql 9.2, but I cannot find Postgis in either central repo or epel 7, any solution please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres provide postgres 9.3 and postgis 2.1 for Centos 7. Link [here](http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repoview/letter_p.group.html).

Hopes  it helps.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easy yum path. Seems like this is the only option I have currently. Thanks.

Comment: @fengye87, you can simply add postgresql.org's specific repository to your Yum repos. Eliminating manual package install and dependency nightmares which will surely ensue.

Comment: @Timusan, yeah, that's what I'm doing right now. I was just trying not to mass up with Postgresql repo like I did under CentOS 6. Still, thanks :)

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

As Soni Harriz already mentioned, you can install PostgreSQL and PostGIS from a Postgresql.org maintained `Yum` repository. Yet, you *do not* need to manually install each package (*that would be a dependency nightmare!*). If you go to the PostgreSQL Yum page:

http://yum.postgresql.org/

You can select which version you wish to install. At the time of writing, this would be version 9.3, found here: http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg93. And more specifically for CentOS 7 here: http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm

This will setup a `Yum` repository and the needed GPG keys so you do not have to go and manually install the packages. More detailed install/setup information can be found [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation).

These repositories have a full install script available which will also initiate your cluster.

Comment: See some instructions [on the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation)

Comment: @MikeT: Correct, the same link was already stated in my answer.